# How to find someone changed their Twitter profile image?

Tags: image, image-processing, twitter

Say, with in my application, I have a list of friends (Twitter IDs) the user follow. I show their name and their image (from Twitter). Every time the user logs into the application, I want to get the recent profile display image from Twitter.

How do I know, someone changed their Twitter profile image?

Currently, I think, I need to get their image (I use Twitter API: GET users/profile_image/:screen_name) and find the modify time and if it is not newer, I assume it is not changed. Is there a better way of doing it? How would you do if you have to built something like this? I hate getting all the image files and checking them one after one. I hope there is a better way to get the images of those who have made a change to their profile recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json and see if anything in there tracks profile changes although I doubt it. (Try using: https://dev.twitter.com/console for an easier interface).

If you can't find anything in the API, then there is not way to know that the profile image has changed without checking.  In which case, you can store a hash of the old image, and compare the hash of any new images, and see if they match.  If they do not, then you know it has changed.

Hope that helps.